# Webpack 4 - How to configure minimize?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

Webpack 4 comes with the following statement:

> Error: `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` has been removed, please use `config.optimization.minimize` instead.

Fair enough, but I cannot find any information about configuring the UglifyJsPlugin instance running under the hood, for example to change the cache directory. Can this be done?

Comment: For reference, the `UglifyJsPlugin` defaults are listed [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin#options)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It's not possible to modify the default configuration.

You can use the `optimization.minimizer` setting to instantiate your own `UglifyJsPlugin`, however. Using 4.0 we used this example to get source maps even when `mode` is set to `'production'` for example (no longer necessary as of 4.1.1):

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      // we specify a custom UglifyJsPlugin here to get source maps in production
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
          compress: false,
          ecma: 6,
          mangle: true
        },
        sourceMap: true
      })
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Wasn't webpack 4 supposed to be zero conf?

Comment: This requires me to instantiate the plugin though, I just want to modify existing configuration.

Comment: @csvan not possible to configure it, have to instantiate your own to specify a custom configuration

Comment: @connexo I think the example shown above will be unneeded at some point and that the goal is still zero conf but it's not quite there yet! for reference re: this specific example: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6614

Comment: I did what you said and I got an Error:
```ReferenceError: UglifyJsPlugin is not defined```

Comment: @PierreTrollé sorry; I've just added the `require` line to the example :)

Comment: And keep in mind you might need to do `yarn add uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --dev` ;)

Comment: @Karolis correct, as far as I know the docs are not up to date for Webpack 4.x... this information come from a GitHub issue.

Comment: and here; search for "optimization.minimizer" on this page: https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-mode-and-optimization-5423a6bc597a

Comment: one of the GH issues that document this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6879

Comment: @AlfonsoPérez webpack already installs `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` as a dependency

Comment: I am having this same issue. Just updated from Webpack 3 to 4. When i try to build, it starts but fails at the webpack with the error stated above. I have tried the solution above to no avail. Doesn't fix it, and doesn't give me a different error. Where should this be implemented?

Answer (score 8):

Without adding `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`, you can just add this to the end of your **webpack.prod.config.js** file:

```
 optimization: {
   minimize: false
 }
```

Comment: does this answer the question? OP is asking how to configure the plugin, not disable it?

Comment: @Mr5o1 stackoverflow is a public community and the OP is not the only person looking at the answers. Google landed me here because the question was related to my search and this answer is a perfectly valid one which helped me resolve my concern. And I'm not the only one like that. I don't really get those types of comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

webpack.config.js

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
  },
};
```

[webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
yarn add uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --dev
```

Reference: [Alfonso Pérez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225054/alfonso-p%C3%A9rez) answer

Answer (score 1):

For those coming behind me, realized this misleading error was not related to my correct webpack config, but actually, the `offline-plugin` was out of date and causing this issue. It needed to be upgraded. See github issue: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/234#issuecomment-369134047

Answer (score -4):

You should check `p` option: https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#cli-alternatives : this flag tells Webpack to optimize your build for production environment. You can use it with the new "production" `mode` for a smaller build.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to modify the default configuration.