# webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed

Tags: npm, terminal, webpack-4, npm-run

I am working on a udemy course project and upgraded on my packages and modules to their latest version, including webpack4. However, on running npm run-build, I am getting the following error in my terminal.

I have managed to get my dev environment working fine.

```
Error: webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead.
```

I have tried adding the minimizer within Module exports in my webpack.config.prod.js file, as well as installing 'uglifyjs-webpack-plugin' as many forums have suggested but I continue getting the same error.

Package.json

```
  "name": "Burger-Builder-App",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "9.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "chalk": "2.4.2",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
    "eslint": "6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "4.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "promise": "8.0.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^9.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-test-render": "^1.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "url-loader": "2.2.0",
    "webpack": "4.41.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.9.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

WebpackDevServer.config.js

```
const errorOverlayMiddleware = require('react-dev-utils/errorOverlayMiddleware');
const noopServiceWorkerMiddleware = require('react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware');
const config = require('./webpack.config.dev');
const paths = require('./paths');

const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http';
const host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';

module.exports = function(proxy, allowedHost) {
  return {
    // WebpackDevServer 2.4.3 introduced a security fix that prevents remote
    // websites from potentially accessing local content through DNS rebinding:
    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/887
    // https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a
    // However, it made several existing use cases such as development in cloud
    // environment or subdomains in development significantly more complicated:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2271
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2233
    // While we're investigating better solutions, for now we will take a
    // compromise. Since our WDS configuration only serves files in the `public`
    // folder we won't consider accessing them a vulnerability. However, if you
    // use the `proxy` feature, it gets more dangerous because it can expose
    // remote code execution vulnerabilities in backends like Django and Rails.
    // So we will disable the host check normally, but enable it if you have
    // specified the `proxy` setting. Finally, we let you override it if you
    // really know what you're doing with a special environment variable.
    disableHostCheck:
      !proxy || process.env.DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK === 'true',
    // Enable gzip compression of generated files.
    compress: true,
    // Silence WebpackDevServer's own logs since they're generally not useful.
    // It will still show compile warnings and errors with this setting.
    clientLogLevel: 'none',
    // By default WebpackDevServer serves physical files from current directory
    // in addition to all the virtual build products that it serves from memory.
    // This is confusing because those files won’t automatically be available in
    // production build folder unless we copy them. However, copying the whole
    // project directory is dangerous because we may expose sensitive files.
    // Instead, we establish a convention that only files in `public` directory
    // get served. Our build script will copy `public` into the `build` folder.
    // In `index.html`, you can get URL of `public` folder with %PUBLIC_URL%:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In JavaScript code, you can access it with `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`.
    // Note that we only recommend to use `public` folder as an escape hatch
    // for files like `favicon.ico`, `manifest.json`, and libraries that are
    // for some reason broken when imported through Webpack. If you just want to
    // use an image, put it in `src` and `import` it from JavaScript instead.
    contentBase: paths.appPublic,
    // By default files from `contentBase` will not trigger a page reload.
    watchContentBase: true,
    // Enable hot reloading server. It will provide /sockjs-node/ endpoint
    // for the WebpackDevServer client so it can learn when the files were
    // updated. The WebpackDevServer client is included as an entry point
    // in the Webpack development configuration. Note that only changes
    // to CSS are currently hot reloaded. JS changes will refresh the browser.
    hot: true,
    // It is important to tell WebpackDevServer to use the same "root" path
    // as we specified in the config. In development, we always serve from /.
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    // WebpackDevServer is noisy by default so we emit custom message instead
    // by listening to the compiler events with `compiler.plugin` calls above.
    quiet: true,
    // Reportedly, this avoids CPU overload on some systems.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/293
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: /node_modules/,
    },
    // Enable HTTPS if the HTTPS environment variable is set to 'true'
    https: protocol === 'https',
    host: host,
    overlay: false,
    historyApiFallback: {
      // Paths with dots should still use the history fallback.
      // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/387.
      disableDotRule: true,
    },
    public: allowedHost,
    proxy,
    setup(app) {
      // This lets us open files from the runtime error overlay.
      app.use(errorOverlayMiddleware());
      // This service worker file is effectively a 'no-op' that will reset any
      // previous service worker registered for the same host:port combination.
      // We do this in development to avoid hitting the production cache if
      // it used the same host and port.
      // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2272#issuecomment-302832432
      app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware());
    },
  };
};
```

webpack.config.prod.js

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const paths = require('./paths');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
const publicPath = paths.servedPath;
// Some apps do not use client-side routing with pushState.
// For these, "homepage" can be set to "." to enable relative asset paths.
const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === './';
// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
const publicUrl = publicPath.slice(0, -1);
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// Assert this just to be safe.
// Development builds of React are slow and not intended for production.
if (env.stringified['process.env'].NODE_ENV !== '"production"') {
  throw new Error('Production builds must have NODE_ENV=production.');
}

// Note: defined here because it will be used more than once.
const cssFilename = 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css';

// ExtractTextPlugin expects the build output to be flat.
// (See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/27)
// However, our output is structured with css, js and media folders.
// To have this structure working with relative paths, we have to use custom options.
const extractTextPluginOptions = shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths
  ? // Making sure that the publicPath goes back to to build folder.
    { publicPath: Array(cssFilename.split('/').length).join('../') }
  : {};

// This is the production configuration.
// It compiles slowly and is focused on producing a fast and minimal bundle.
// The development configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        // we specify a custom UglifyJsPlugin here to get source maps in production
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
          cache: true,
          parallel: true,
          uglifyOptions: {
            compress: false,
            ecma: 6,
            mangle: true
          },
          sourceMap: true
        })
      ]
    },
  // Don't attempt to continue if there are any errors.
  bail: true,
  // We generate sourcemaps in production. This is slow but gives good results.
  // You can exclude the *.map files from the build during deployment.
  devtool: shouldUseSourceMap ? 'source-map' : false,
  // In production, we only want to load the polyfills and the app code.
  entry: [require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs],
  output: {
    // The build folder.
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
    // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
    // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
    // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
    publicPath: publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path
        .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
        .replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // TODO: Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      // We are waiting for https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2176.
      // { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      // First, run the linter.
      // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter,
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
              
            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
        // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
        // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
        oneOf: [
          // "url" loader works just like "file" loader but it also embeds
          // assets smaller than specified size as data URLs to avoid requests.
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          // Process JS with Babel.
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              
              compact: true,
            },
          },
          // The notation here is somewhat confusing.
          // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
          // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
          // "style" loader normally turns CSS into JS modules injecting <style>,
          // but unlike in development configuration, we do something different.
          // `ExtractTextPlugin` first applies the "postcss" and "css" loaders
          // (second argument), then grabs the result CSS and puts it into a
          // separate file in our build process. This way we actually ship
          // a single CSS file in production instead of JS code injecting <style>
          // tags. If you use code splitting, however, any async bundles will still
          // use the "style" loader inside the async code so CSS from them won't be
          // in the main CSS file.
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
              Object.assign(
                {
                  fallback: require.resolve('style-loader'),
                  use: [
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                      options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        minimize: true,
                        sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                        modules: true,
                        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                      options: {
                        // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                        ident: 'postcss',
                        plugins: () => [
                          require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                          autoprefixer({
                            browsers: [
                              '>1%',
                              'last 4 versions',
                              'Firefox ESR',
                              'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                            ],
                            flexbox: 'no-2009',
                          }),
                        ],
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
                extractTextPluginOptions
              )
            ),
            // Note: this won't work without `new ExtractTextPlugin()` in `plugins`.
          },
          // "file" loader makes sure assets end up in the `build` folder.
          // When you `import` an asset, you get its filename.
          // This loader don't uses a "test" so it will catch all modules
          // that fall through the other loaders.
          {
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
            // it's runtime that would otherwise processed through "file" loader.
            // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
            // by webpacks internal loaders.
            exclude: [/\.js$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
          // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In production, it will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
    // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
    }),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV was set to production here.
    // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // Minify the code.
    // Note: this won't work without ExtractTextPlugin.extract(..) in `loaders`.
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: cssFilename,
    }),
    // Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
    // to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
    // having to parse `index.html`.
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
    }),
    // Generate a service worker script that will precache, and keep up to date,
    // the HTML & assets that are part of the Webpack build.
    new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
      // By default, a cache-busting query parameter is appended to requests
      // used to populate the caches, to ensure the responses are fresh.
      // If a URL is already hashed by Webpack, then there is no concern
      // about it being stale, and the cache-busting can be skipped.
      dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{8}\./,
      filename: 'service-worker.js',
      logger(message) {
        if (message.indexOf('Total precache size is') === 0) {
          // This message occurs for every build and is a bit too noisy.
          return;
        }
        if (message.indexOf('Skipping static resource') === 0) {
          // This message obscures real errors so we ignore it.
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2612
          return;
        }
        console.log(message);
      },
      minify: true,
      // For unknown URLs, fallback to the index page
      navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',
      // Ignores URLs starting from /__ (useful for Firebase):
      // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2237#issuecomment-302693219
      navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__).*/],
      // Don't precache sourcemaps (they're large) and build asset manifest:
      staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
    }),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
  ],
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
};
```

Not quite sure how to solve this as new to webpack. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem after updating from Webpack 3

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053215/webpack-4-how-to-configure-minimize